# How to hide/mask extra vars passed to ansible tower

Tags: ansible, hide, mask, ansible-tower

I am passing a password value as extra vars to my playbook in Ansible tower 3.x.
The playbook runs fine, however the password value is visible in the Extra vars section of  executed jobs of Ansible tower.I have tried no-log: True but it does not help me as it probably controls the log display but not the data shown in extra vars section of executed jobs.

An important point to be noted here is that the ansible playbook is invoked from another 3rd party application as an automated task.

Is there any way that i can make ansible tower not show(or mask) this extra variable?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot mask/hide the extra_vars in job_template in Ansible Tower. But you can use Survey option to capture values for variables and select answer type as password, automatically value will be masked/hidden.. Refer [Documentation here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html#surveys)

Comment: Hello Krishna..many thanks for the guidance.i have a query though..The playbook is invoked from an external system and the user would not have access to the ansible tower realtime.If i use survey,on execution it would be promoted for real-time entry of values right??

Comment: Yes survey option would prompt for real-time entry. Since the playbook is invoked from an external system. while invoking the job template, I guess values can be passed to survey_spec.. which will be available form api `api/v2/job_templates/<job_template_id>/survey_spec/`